# Django reverse mapping

Tags: django

I have following files

**directory/urls.py** (project)

```
url(r'^$', include('dirapp.urls', namespace='dirapp')),
```

**dirapp/urls.py** (app)

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

**But when I go to shell I cannot do reverse, all these are not succesfull**

```
reverse('dirapp')
reverse('dirapp:detail', kwargs={'pk':1})
```

Comment: You need to remove the `$` in your first url shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect

```
views.DetailView.as_view()
```

There has to be a correct view extended from DetailView, e.g.

```
views.PersonDetail.as_view()
```

Second thing, unfortunately you need to restart shell for changes to take effects!

Also if there is a namespace all urls needs to be resolved using this

```
reverse('namespace:name'), e.g. reverse('dirapp:index')
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `$` in `url(r'^$', include('dirapp.urls', namespace='dirapp'))`

This indicates the end of the URL patter.

It should be

```
url(r'^', include('dirapp.urls', namespace='dirapp'))
```

Read more about [including URL patterns here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Comment: unfortunately I have same results regardless if $ is or not there :(

Comment: `reverse('dirapp')` is not valid. Try `reverse('detail', args=[1])` . More [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) . the `kwargs` should work too

Comment: I got it working, unfortunately I did several changes and could not find out which helped. But I found few bugs in code anyway...

Comment: Main thing over here is that you need to restart shell in order for changes in routing to takes effects. I did not know that :(